# Python socket-module: How to change the local port on the client side?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp, port

I want to get packages from a network using TCP/IP as a client.

With ...

```
connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
```

... I can change the port of the peer address. But I change the port of my local computer?

EDIT: I want to use a network card with four ports. The network card is connected to a measurement device which sends a lot of data. How can I see where the data goes? How can I distinguish between this four ports?

Comment: Uhm... Can you elaborate? What port you want to change on your local computer? If you are connecting to a remove TCP port, what local port you want to change?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assume you have a socket named `sock`... use `socket.bind()`

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
DESTINATION_ADDR = '1.1.1.1'
SOURCE_PORT, DESTINATION_PORT = 31415, 80
sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', SOURCE_PORT))
sock.connect((DESTINATION_ADDR, DESTINATION_PORT))
```

Now I run `tshark` (text `wireshark`) to see my traffic on that interface...

```
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$ sudo tshark -i eth0 tcp and port 31415
Capturing on eth0
  0.000000 24.19.161.6 -> 1.1.1.1      TCP 31415 > http [SYN] Seq=0 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460 TSV=4228124209 TSER=0 WS=6
 12.000009 24.19.161.6 -> 1.1.1.1      TCP 31415 > http [SYN] Seq=0 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460 TSV=4228127209 TSER=0 WS=6
 36.000010 24.19.161.6 -> 1.1.1.1      TCP 31415 > http [SYN] Seq=0 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460 TSV=4228133209 TSER=0 WS=6
```

Comment: But i am on the client-side. The measurement device is the server.

Comment: @kame, it doesn't matter... you can also `bind()` before a `connect()`

Comment: @kame, are you trying to route traffic out a different ethernet interface?

Comment: I want to receive data from a measurement device. Because there is a huge amount of data, i have to receive the data parallel on 4 ports. The device has also 4 ports.

Comment: how do you send a message after the last line, the connect? The client connects but not data is being sent. How do you do that?

Answer (score 2):

The four *physical* ports on your network adapter are **not** related to the *logical* port concept of IP (and TCP/IP).

Before we can help you further, please specify what is the configuration (i.e. IP address, subnet etc) of these *physical* ports. There might be a way to do what you want in Python: select one of the four ports for the traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* assign a TCP/IP client port, but you should not because it doesn't make any sense to do so. See [TCP/IP Client (Ephemeral) Ports and Client/Server Application Port Use](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPIPClientEphemeralPortsandClientServerApplicatio.htm) for an explanation.

Comment: If you can't do it, why am I able to do it in my answer ;-)?

Comment: @Mike Pennington: I am clearly an idiot (or at least someone who needs more sleep) :-)

Comment: I agree that this is an odd request from a normal TCP client-server perspective... I'm curious to find out what he's really doing, but I think English may not be his native tongue