# How to set client's port when sending REST GET in Python?

Tags: sockets, python-requests, esp8266, micropython

I have some very basic networking-related questions:

1. In the Python requests library, if I want to make a REST GET call, I know that internally a socket is created to send and receive the GET request and response. As for the port on which the socket is created, I understand it would be random in free range, please correct if I'm wrong.
2. If I want to make such a REST GET call on the client, a particular port is used, is it possible to do that?

While 2 may seem like a weird requirement, I do have a use case for it. So please let me know if it's possible.

## EDIT 1:

If I may extend the second question for 8266, is it possible to specify the client port when sending REST GET packet from 8266 in Micropython?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6250263/5552095 - Would something like this work for you?

Comment: "I have some very basic networking related questions:" ----> "Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault."