# How do I explicitly set which port my TCP client is listening on?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, server, port

Say I have a server and client similar to the code below which is taken from here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication#Client

Server:

```
   1 #!/usr/bin/env python

   3 import socket
   4 
   5 
   6 TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
   7 TCP_PORT = 5005
   8 BUFFER_SIZE = 20  # Normally 1024, but we want fast response
   9 
  10 s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  11 s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
  12 s.listen(1)
  13 
  14 conn, addr = s.accept()
  15 print 'Connection address:', addr
  16 while 1:
  17     data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
  18     if not data: break
  19     print "received data:", data
  20     conn.send(data)  # echo
  21 conn.close()
```

Client:

```
   1 #!/usr/bin/env python
   2 
   3 import socket
   4 
   5 
   6 TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
   7 TCP_PORT = 5005
   8 BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
   9 MESSAGE = "Hello, World!"
  10 
  11 s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  12 s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
  13 s.send(MESSAGE)
  14 data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
  15 s.close()
  16 
  17 print "received data:", data
```

Seems to me when the client connects to the server it is assigned a somewhat random port that it will listen on for responses.

My question is how do I explicitly set which port my client will listen for a responses on and communicate that to the server?

I want to receive msg's from my server to my client which should be listening on port 5023 for example rather than some randomly assigned port.

Comment: "_I want to receive msg's from my server to my client which should be listening on port 5023 for example rather than some randomly assigned port._" Why? It's really only a host listening for a connection that needs to have a fixed port. Once the connection is made, it doesn't matter what the ports are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket


TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
MESSAGE = "Hello, World!"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('',5023))
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.send(MESSAGE)
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
s.close()

print("received data:", data)
```

Use bind after you create the socket. Just tested this on Py3, it looks to me you're on Py2.7 but it should work the same.

Answer (score 1):

This question could should be marked as duplicate. The original answer is here:
[Python socket-module: How to change the local port on the client side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250198/python-socket-module-how-to-change-the-local-port-on-the-client-side#6250263)

Basically before the client calls the connect() they have the option to

```
bind((HOST, PORT)
```

Where HOST is the ip address of the client and PORT is the port the client would like to listen on.

Answer (score 0):

I think your client listens to the TCP_PORT as you set in `s.connect`; and your server listens on the TCP_PORT you set in `s.bind`

Comment: TCP_PORT is the port the server is listening on as well so they must be the same for a connection

Comment: @ryanpickles But isn't the server port only the port that the server initially (always) listens on, but in order to establish a connection with a client, another port is used? Otherwise other clients couldn't use the service anymore. The server would only be able to serve one client at a time.